# Can a workflow move a document?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-library

More specifically I was wondering if a sharepoint designer workflow can move a document into a folder once it has been approved.

And if it can move a document into a folder once it is approved can the workflow move the doc into the folder that has the same name and account number for that document?

And if there is no folder with the name and account number of the document is it able to create a new one?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Copying and then deleting a document is certainly not the same as moving it. Among other things, it will not preserve the document history, if it has a document ID it will not be preserved etc.

In your workflow, you just need to “Update List Item” and update the “Path and Name” field with the folder name where the document should be moved in. If the destination folder has different permissions and the current user cannot actually access it, you will need to add an impersonation step in the beginning of the workflow.

Comment: very interesting im going to give this a shot today and i will report back how it works out. Thank You!

Comment: I have done it for SP2010 and worked as expected, but please verify it too.

Comment: I don't have a field called Path and Name in my list.  I have a field called Attachments, but that just looks like a boolean flag that lets me know if there's an attachment.  You know, because you can't just look in the attachment's location and see that it's null or anything.  Stupid SharePoint.

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can use the "Copy" function and then the "Delete" function. So you have the same "Move" functionality.

Comment: Okay so i can have the workflow copy the file to the folder and then delete the original file?

Comment: Yes! Perform the following actions: copy and then delete.

Comment: All in the same workflow

Comment: I don't see an option to copy the document into a specific folder it only lets me copy it to another library. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You it's right. But you can use this library with a repository of this documents. I had understood that the folder would be a repository for this document, sorry.

Comment: If you need a folder you can use JQuery, but it's a complicated question.