# Move documetns with workflow

Tags: workflow, document-library, content-type, visual-studio, document

We are using SP 2013 on-prem with a separate server for Workflow (Workflow Service 2013).

I am using Visual Studio to create a workflow. I want the workflow to be able to move the document it is run on to another site, and keep it's metadata and document id (which is generated by the document id service).  I also need to move the version log along to the destination site.

The scope for moving the document is within the same site collection, and all the document libraries use the same content type as default.

Can I achieve this (moving documents with workflow) without developing custom code? Looking for some tips, references and adivce here.

Comment: You'll lose the ID and version history when you move the document. See here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117952/can-a-workflow-move-a-document

Comment: As I understand it, it will lose the Id when copied, not moved, or maybe I am misunderstanding here ?

Comment: I've done it before. It loses the version history and ID when it moves to a different library.

Comment: Yes, the ID will change, but not the Document ID (which is generated by the Document ID service)

Answer (score 1):

If it is on premise, you can create a custom workflow activity for SharePoint Designer. This will require some custom code though

Comment: It is on-premise, and I am using Visual Studio. I would be most interested in some information about custom workflow activity.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163911.aspx... refer this link

Comment: Custom code in workflows is only supported with the SharePoint 2010 workflow model! With the newer SharePoint 2013 workflow model you need to use the HttpSend action to make a call-out to a custom service that will move the document for you.

Answer (score 1):

My company has a product [CopyMove for SharePoint](http://www.sharepointproducts.com/Pages/CopyMove2013-Overview.aspx) that can do this. However, there is a price tag to it. But you can start with a free trial. It's a server-side install (WSP package) and it supports Copy and Move from SharePoint 2010/2013 workflows. Check out this [example](http://documentation.sharepointproducts.com/CopyMove2013/copymove_sp2013_workflow.htm) in the product documentation.

There is also support for the document id service so that IDs are preserved on moves.

Comment: This example is copying. You got example of moving. And, do you know which method\fucntion I can use if I am developing the move functionality ? I tried the SPFile.MoveTO, but it can only move documents inside the same site.

Comment: Yes, indeed! Let me support you by email.